# Android: Unable to instantiate service...can't instantiate class com.stocktickerwidget.AppWidget$UpdateService; no empty constructor

Tags: android, service, constructor

Please help.

`Android: Unable to instantiate service...can't instantiate class com.stocktickerwidget.AppWidget$UpdateService; no empty constructor`

I get the error above,

I do not understand why.

Thank you

```
public class UpdateService extends Service {
    public UpdateService() {
       //
        }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e("", "onStartCommand di AppWidget");
        int[] appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra("widgetsids");
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);

        // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to
        // this provider

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            Log.e("",
                    "i=" + Integer.toString(i) + " di "
                            + Integer.toString(N));
            RemoteViews view = buildUpdate(getApplicationContext(),
                    appWidgetIds);

            // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current
            // app widget
            manager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);

        }
        return (START_NOT_STICKY);

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, delete your constructor, as you inherit a public zero-argument constructor from `Service`.

Then, either make this be a `static` inner class, or make it be a standalone public Java class. You cannot use a regular inner class here, as Android has no way of creating an instance of that inner class.

Comment: `static` inner class should also be `public`